# Configurable AND Bundle Product?

Tags: configurable-product, bundled-product

So I have a product that comes in 5 different colors. So basically I make a Configurable Product, then under Associated Products I make the 5 Simple Products (for my colors).

So I have 6 records now (1 config, 5 simple)

Then I want to make a Bundled Product out of it. I entered that in and under Bundled Products, I use the 5 Simple Products plus another product that works with it and save all that.

Is this the correct way?

Comment: Yes. And now I'm entering more text because SE wants you to type a lot.

Comment: HAHA - I thought it seems strange to basically have an extra SKU, extra product description, etc. in that Configurable one. It's like a useless entry.

Comment: If you don't want to show the configurable product in the shop but only the bundle, you can delete it.

Comment: Yep. Definitely deleted the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Since you cannot nest complex product types in Magento (i.e. bundle configurable products) you need to bundle the simple products. You are lucky that you only have one configurable attribute, so it looks the same way for the customer (one dropdown for the "configurable" product).